# Does Smack support XMPP end-to-end encryption (E2EE)?

Tags: encryption, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, end-to-end-encryption

Is there any way to make end-to-end encryption with a [Smack](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)? Does Smack have built-in support for e.g. OpenPGP (RFC 4880)?

I need to use e2e encryption with ejabberd server.

Answer (score 1):

Smack has support for

- [XEP-0373: OpenPGP for XMPP](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0373.html) in Smack's *smack-openpgp* module within the `org.jivesoftware.smackx.ox` package.
- [XEP-0384: OMEMO Encryption](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0384.html) in Smack's *smack-omemo* module within the `org.jivesoftware.smackx.omemo` package.

Answer (score 0):

smack integrated signal protocol,maybe siginal can satisfied your demand.check [smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) at github.